# Connection between harmonic potential and particle intepretation

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I just finished a quantum mechanics course, but I still have some problems. In the simple harmonics potential well, energy between two adjacent states is always $\hbar\omega$. I read that this can be interpreted as adding a quanta to get to the next energy sate, and these quanta behave like particles with energy $\hbar\omega$. If I consider an infinite square potential well now, the quantized energy is $\frac{n^{2}\pi^{2}\hbar^{2}}{2mL^{2}}$, and the energy difference beween two states are not equal. In the infinite potential well case, is the particle interpretation still correct?

Comment: Your question title is about when two systems have evenly spaced bound states. Your question text is about whether we can use particle interpretations ("quanta of energy") when they are not. Which are you asking?

Comment: What I mean is that does the interpretation of energy quanta used in equally spaced energy system still work in those whose energy aren't equally spaced?

Comment: Well, given that the levels are _unevenly_ spaced, the answer is no. Also, I would suggest being more clear - your 'infinite potential well' case is for a square well. The harmonic potential well can be infinite as well; it is just shaped differently.

Comment: If the answer is no, then what is so special about harmonic oscillator that this energy quanta interpretation can be used? Or is it just a happy coincidence?

Comment: @Daniel , harmonic oscillator is directly related to the Fourier representation of waves and we observe wave-like behaviour of particles.

Answer (score 1):

Particle interpretation indeed can be understood from the point of quantization of electromagnetic field. Basically, as the Maxwell equations are linear, each Fourier mode of the electromagnetic 4-potential $A^\mu$ is independent from others. This greatly simplifies the description, as the system is effectively diagonalized.

Each Fourier mode satisfies the wave equation which, essentially, makes each mode and independent harmonic oscillator. After canonical quantization of these modes, one obtains the quantum oscillators with even (mode-dependent) level spacing.

As in some processes it is fairly easy to measure the energy transferred from electromagnetic field (say, in photoelectric effect), one can imagine that the field consists of particles with different energy.

---

As to a question, why the harmonic potential, it is actually the simplest one both in terms of position and momentum space beside the trivial ones (the square box looks really bad in k-space). Luckily, quadratic Hamiltonians are both abundant in nature and are almost the only ones we can exactly solve.

I guess there might be a different particle-like interpretation for another evenly-spaced potential, but it definitely won't be as natural.

Answer (score 0):

The interpretation that you cite dates from the early days of QED (prior to Feynman and renormaluzation).  Excitation of the field were treated by purturbation theory based upon small oscillations which leads to an HO spectrum. The excitation were then interpreted as single photons.  It was the small oscillations approximation that leads to evenly spaced levels.